# BIOS won't save setup password after restarting

Tags: windows-10, bios

I recently got a new batch of PCs. One of my new PCs has trouble with the BIOS. For the network installation to run correctly some settings in the BIOS have to be changed.

System security needs to have embedded security device enabled. For this to happen there must be a setup password, but after every reboot the password gets erased, and the date/time resets itself. No other PC has acted like this before. BIOS has been reset and the CMOS battery has been replaced.

System specs:

HP z420 workstation.

OS version: Windows 10 1709.

System BIOS: J61 V03.94

Has anybody else run in to this problem and found a way to fix this? Any help would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the battery you installed was also bad... if not, you're looking at a corrupted BIOS load or bad motherboard.  I'd test the battery with a meter 1st, then try the BIOS update (no cost option), before calling the motherboard bad.

Comment: Alright i'll try that thanks. If that doesn't work i'm going to send it back to the distributor.